# text display outside the block

Tags: css

I tried the display:table-cell but it didn't worked. How can I show the word inside the div. Now it show overflow the div. I am use CSS2 on my webpage. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div style=" width:60px; border-style: solid; border-width: 15px; display: block;">
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schoolseeeeee   </a> 
</div>
<div style="float: right; border-color: #ff33ff" width:50%;>Column 2</div>
```

Comment: Make the font smaller or the box bigger.

Comment: So you're wanting the overflow text to hide, the box to grow, or the text to wrap?

Comment: Are you just asking how to make the text fit in a box that you intentionally set too narrow for it?

Answer (score 0):

Use word-wrap:

```
a{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1sfcj1d2/)

Comment: It is har dly ever c orrect to br eak w ords t hat way. The cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: But it is exactly what he is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of the div container to allow the content to fit. Right now you have it set to 60px, which is not wide enough for the text to display without overflowing. You could do something like this instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="width:150px;  border-style: solid;
 border-width: 15px; display: block; text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Visit W3Schoolseeeeee   </a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; border-color: #ff33ff" width:50%;>Column 2</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This example really isn't leveraging best practices of HTML and CSS. Ideally your CSS would be outside of the HTML document entirely, and you likely don't need to hard code a pixel width for your div container.